# Двойные стандарты компилятора

Tags: c++, clang, warning, неопределённое-поведение

```
int a[42]{};
std::cout << a[42];

std::string str(42, 'x');
std::cout << str[42];
```

Почему в первом случае срабатывает предупреждение о неопределенном поведении, а во втором нет?

Comment: А что, `string`- это тоже массив (это к "двойным стандартам")?

Comment: @Harry ну доступ же одинаковый, внутри там массив

Comment: [If pos is equal to the string length, the function returns a reference to the null character that follows the last character in the string (which should not be modified).](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/)

Comment: @SKIP перенесите в ответ

Comment: По стандарту предупреждения не требуется ни в первом, ни во втором случае.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для `string` доступ к элементу в позиции с индексом равным длине не ведет к неопределенному поведению.

Вот что говорит [стандарт](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.access):

> **21.3.2.5 Element access[string.access]**
>
> constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
> constexpr reference       operator[](size_type pos);
>
> 1. *Preconditions:* pos <= size().
> 2. *Returns:* *(begin() + pos) if pos < size(). Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type charT with value charT(), where modifying the object to any value other than charT() leads to undefined behavior.
> 3. *Throws:* Nothing.

В следующем коде имеет место случай 2, а именно `pos == size()`, а тут поведение определено однозначно:

```
std::string str(42, 'x');
std::cout << str[42];
```

Comment: *where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior.* -> *where modifying the object **to any value other than charT()** leads to undefined behavior.*

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/string.access, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Answer (score 0):

Потому что теоретически, у класса string квадратные скобки могут быть переопределены и запускать ракету на Марс.

Comment: Если вдаваться в подробности безопасности исключений и работы контейнера, то  есть резон знать почему именно так реализован оператор, а не иначе